# Refactor tool for Dart in VScode not working

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter and I am unable to use the refactor tool in VS code for windows.

Instead of seeing the options such as "wrap with container" I only have "Extract Method" and "Extract Local variable".

I have checked and as I have recently installed of 2 days ago, I'm pretty sure I have the latest version installed of Flutter SDK (3.10.05) and Dart 3.0.5.

Comment: Your subject line says "Dart".  Are you talking about a Flutter app, or a pure dart app?  A dart app will not have flutter-related refactorings.  The extension determines this by examining the pubspec.yaml.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the correct extension installed in vs code.

steps can be seen here:
https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/editor?tab=vscode